# working with inetAton and Inetntoa in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I'm writing an application that queries a Db for which IP addresses are represented by their inetaton equivalent.   I need to be able to take an Ip address input and convert it to inetaton in order to use it with my DB. also I need to be able to work in the other direction (is integer to string).  I've written a function to mimic aton but ntoa is very non-trivial. does anyone know of a .NET function that can do this for me, so I don't have to reinvent the wheel?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [windows equivalent of inet_aton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420663/windows-equivalent-of-inet-aton)

Comment: Not the same.  I am not doing any type of socket programming, I just need a simple way to go from int to ipstr (and visa-versa) using a method similar to aton or ntoa.