# Convert a Poco::IPAddress into ulong

Tags: c++, ip-address, poco

Under boost there is :

```
boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("192.168.0.10").to_ulong()
```

It convert `192.168.0.10` into `0xC0A8010A`

which is very comfortable. Unfortunately, I don't have boost on this project but poco. I don't find any method which permit to do that.

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Is the ip adress guaranteed to be *IPv4*? Because *IPv6* definitely doesn't fit in an `ulong` anymore...

Comment: Can you use [inet_aton](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton)? (See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420663/windows-equivalent-of-inet-aton if you're using winsock)

Comment: Is that typo in the example? It should be like this: `0xC0A8000A = 192*0x1000000+168*0x10000+0*0x100+10` I get a different result than `0xC0A8010A` (I am mixing binary and decimal, but I corrected it in calculator)

Comment: @CommuSoft, yes i look only for an IPV4 address.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani you're right I've made a little mistake the address is 192.168.1.10 to make 0xC0A8010A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `addr()` method of `POCO::IPAddress` to get `in_addr` struct (if IPv4 is used). The `S_addr` field is your target ulong.